# getting error that no declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0

I am getting the following error

```
Line 84 in XML document from class path resource [car-job-app-context.xml] is 
invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 84; 
columnNumber: 154; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but
no declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'.
```

Here is my file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-2.0.xsd" >

.....

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="pk.training.basitMahmood.service.impl" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="pk.training.basitMahmood.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
```

Here is the snapshot of my maven dependencies

[image: Maven Dependency JARS]

I also saw the same link which says move the `tx declaration` after `context` but it is not working. 
[same post as my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542616/no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-jparepositories). I have tried with before and after combination but the error is still there.

Why i am getting this error ? I am unable to save data in data base .... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the namespaces is irrelevant. Make sure the spring-data-jpa artifact is on your classpath, and double check the schema version. There's no such thing as spring-jpa-2.0. It should be somewhere between 1.0 and 1.3. With Spring, you can usually also omit the version and get the latest schema by default.

Comment: You can see in the picture that i have `spring-data-jpa-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar` in my maven dependencies ? You can see all the jars that i have.

Comment: One thing more, each link is opening except ` http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd"` I also tried ` http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd"` but i am getting page not found ?

Comment: It starts working, i don't know but i put a space in the line `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd ">` and after that it starts working, although i again remove the space but it is still working. I don't know why this is not working before. But at least you gave me idea of checking the links regarding xsd whether it is opening or not. Also you said that order is irrelevant. So thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the definition of the beans schema.

Change `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`

For `xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add in beans;

```
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
```