# Spring JPA: XML Configuration - No qualifying bean of Repository / no declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to move my application from JDBC to Spring JPA.

I have extended `CrudRepository` [of org.springframework.data.repository] and created my own DAO Interface

```
public interface IMyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
// Queries
}
```

But, `IMyRepositoty` bean is not getting created with below XML configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.dao" />
<bean id="projectDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    autowire-candidate="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://ABC:3306/project" />
    <property name="username" value="userA" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
</bean>

<bean id="projectEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="projectDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.project.dao" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
    </props>
    </property>   
</bean>

<bean id="projectJpaTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="projectEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="projectJpaTransactionManager" />

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
    
<!-- <jpa:repositories base-package="com.project.dao"/> -->
</beans>
```

The error is:

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.project.dao.IMyRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

After searching many articles, found that need to add `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.project.dao"/>` into XML. But that is resulting in another error as below

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 68; columnNumber: 69; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

More Info, In dependencies of module I have:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And parent module have dependency on : `spring-jdbc, spring-test, spring-core, spring-context-support, spring-orm` all of version `4.1.6.RELEASE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Spring Docs on JPA repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) :

You need to add this namespace JPA Repository Support :

`xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"`

As well as JPA schema location :

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd"
```

This is missing from your xml file. That's why you are getting that schema error.

---

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <jpa:repositories base-package="com.project.dao" />

</beans>
```

It should work.

Comment: Hi Anish, thanks for the reply. Yes, adding **http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd** indeed solve the issue. But why can't I use CrudRepository!

Comment: Typo was only on stackoverflow. No worries there.

Comment: @Jake You can use crudrepository also.

Comment: @Jake Check here for difference between crudrepository and jparepository :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring

Comment: After those changes I'm running into another error

**
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IMyRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) **

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218888/discussion-between-jake-and-anish-b).

Answer (score 0):

On your Application class you have to use the:

> @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your repositories directory")

and annotate the IMyRepositoty as a

> @Repository

Comment: The problem might be with your XML declaration header refer to this thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542616/no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-jparepositories

Comment: There is no application class, hence the configuration is in XML :|

Comment: @Jake yes i commented a link the related issue under my first proposal.